Correlate values from string_split into multiple rows
I was trying to split the values into multiple rows based on the delimiter ',' in SQL Server.
I have my source table as



FileID
Med1
Med2
Med3
Med4
Med5
Med6




1
Admin, Monitor, Verify
Sodium Tab3

end1, end2, end3
Magnesium Sulphate
Heparin



I want my ouput as



FileID
Med1
Med2
Med3
Med4
Med5
Med6




1
Admin
Sodium Tab3

end1
Magnesium Sulphate
Heparin


1
Monitor
Sodium Tab3

end2
Magnesium Sulphate
Heparin


1
Verify
Sodium Tab3

end3
Magnesium Sulphate
Heparin



Here FileId is the primary key for the source table. I tried using CROSS APPLY,OUTER APPLY to achieve this, but I end up getting 6 rows instead of 3. How do I achieve the following output?
Note: Any of the 6 columns can have the ',' delimiter. I just want to split the values into multiple rows when there is a delimiter, otherwise just keep the same value. Most of my approach resulted in getting cartesian product of rows instead of just 3.
Any help is appreciated.
This is one of the solutions I tried,
select distinct FileID,
    s.value as Med1,
    s1.value as Med2,
    s2.value as Med3,
    s3.value as Med4,
    s4.value as Med5,
    s5.value as Med6
from stage s
outer apply STRING_SPLIT(Med1,',') s
outer apply STRING_SPLIT(Med2,',') s1
outer apply STRING_SPLIT(Med3,',') s2
outer apply STRING_SPLIT(Med4,',') s3
outer apply STRING_SPLIT(Med5,',') s4
outer apply STRING_SPLIT(Med6,',') s5

For the above example, this query gives me 6 rows instead of 3.
EDIT:
If one column has 2 delimiters and another column will has 3 delimiters then we just paste the second value to the remaining. Suppose in the above example if Med1 had only Admin,Monitor then this would be the output



FileID
Med1
Med2
Med3
Med4
Med5
Med6




1
Admin
Sodium Tab3

end1
Magnesium Sulphate
Heparin


1
Monitor
Sodium Tab3

end2
Magnesium Sulphate
Heparin


1
Monitor
Sodium Tab3

end3
Magnesium Sulphate
Heparin




Didn't you ask the same thing only a few days ago?

Imagine a scenario where each of the 6 columns have a different number of comma separated values e.g. 2, 3, 4, 5,  6, 7. What results do you expect? How should they be combined together?

@tim I don't think the dup is correct. OP can split the rows but they seem to want to combine them in a specific way - which they need to clarify.

The expected order is just the current order of the CSV items.

They are splitting multiple columns, and combining them

@DaleK if the one column has 2 delimiters then other column will also has the same 2 delimiters or no delimiter or NULL. We do not have a scenario where columns have different number of delimiters

@DaleK yes I had asked the question 2 days back as well. Since I had posted a photo of the table my question got closed and I wasn’t able to find an answer. I’ve been trying to figure out a solution for a more than a week

Does this answer your question? Store multiple comma separated strings into temp table

Does this answer your question? STRING_SPLIT with string position

@ThomA This won’t work for my use case

It seems the logic you want is:

Split a string only if it has a delimiter, otherwise use the same value on all rows. We can use a CASE and LIKE to conditionally split it.
Join all split columns by the ordinal. It's a bit involved, but you can use STRING_SPLIT with the new ordinal column, and FULL JOIN them all together.

SELECT
  s.FileID,
  v.*
FROM stage s
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT
      ISNULL(TRIM(m1.value), s.Med1) AS Med1,
      ISNULL(TRIM(m2.value), s.Med2) AS Med2,
      ISNULL(TRIM(m3.value), s.Med3) AS Med3,
      ISNULL(TRIM(m4.value), s.Med4) AS Med4,
      ISNULL(TRIM(m5.value), s.Med5) AS Med5,
      ISNULL(TRIM(m6.value), s.Med6) AS Med6
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(CASE WHEN s.Med1 LIKE '%,%' THEN s.Med1 END, ',', 1) m1
    FULL JOIN STRING_SPLIT(CASE WHEN s.Med2 LIKE '%,%' THEN s.Med2 END, ',', 1) m2 ON m2.ordinal = m1.ordinal
    FULL JOIN STRING_SPLIT(CASE WHEN s.Med3 LIKE '%,%' THEN s.Med3 END, ',', 1) m3 ON m3.ordinal = ISNULL(m2.ordinal, m1.ordinal)
    FULL JOIN STRING_SPLIT(CASE WHEN s.Med4 LIKE '%,%' THEN s.Med4 END, ',', 1) m4 ON m4.ordinal = ISNULL(m3.ordinal, ISNULL(m2.ordinal, m1.ordinal))
    FULL JOIN STRING_SPLIT(CASE WHEN s.Med5 LIKE '%,%' THEN s.Med5 END, ',', 1) m5 ON m5.ordinal = ISNULL(m4.ordinal, ISNULL(m3.ordinal, ISNULL(m2.ordinal, m1.ordinal)))
    FULL JOIN STRING_SPLIT(CASE WHEN s.Med6 LIKE '%,%' THEN s.Med6 END, ',', 1) m6 ON m6.ordinal = ISNULL(m5.ordinal, ISNULL(m4.ordinal, ISNULL(m3.ordinal, ISNULL(m2.ordinal, m1.ordinal))))
) v;

db<>fiddle
Once you've done all that you will start to realize why you shouldn't store lists in a single column in the first place.

Wouldn't COALESCE make this a bit more concise? Nice solution btw!

Yes it would, but I don't like it: it compiles to a giant CASE and does weird things with subqueries and implicit conversions. ISNULL behaves much better, just more verbose.

@Charlieface, this works only if the number of element in any of the Med is either ONE or THREE. The result is weird when one of the Med has only TWO element. Example : try 'Heparin, Test' for the last Med6`

Correct, you get nulls in the remaining rows in such a case, but OP stated that's actually not possible in their data so I didn't deal with it.

Thanks for the solution  @Charlieface got an update to this problem. There can be scenarios with different separators. If med 1 has a,b and med 2 has c,d,e then med 1 values will be a,b,b and med 2 will be c,d,e. I tweaked your query but still failed to get the req solution –

I suggest you create a new question for that as this question is already answered. And please be very clear about the desired logic and show sample data and expected results.


In the CTEs split the rows and rank the rows.
Ranked rows are then joined so that the sequence matches.
Tested the code when med1 and med4 contains different sizes of comma separated values.

Assumption : Only Med1 and Med4 have comma separated values.you can extend the CTEs for other columns in case they have comma separated values.
Fiddle
WITH Med1Splits AS (
    SELECT 
        t.FileID,
        Med1Split.value AS Med1,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.FileID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rn
    FROM test t
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(t.Med1, ',') AS Med1Split
),
Med4Splits AS (
    SELECT 
        t.FileID,
        Med4Split.value AS Med4,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.FileID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rn
    FROM test t
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(t.Med4, ',') AS Med4Split
)
SELECT 
    t.FileID,  
    m1.Med1,
    t.Med2,
    t.Med3,
    m4.Med4,
    t.Med5,
    t.Med6
FROM 
    Med1Splits m1
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    Med4Splits m4 ON m1.FileID = m4.FileID AND m1.rn = m4.rn
JOIN 
    test t ON t.FileID = COALESCE(m1.FileID, m4.FileID);  


Thanks for the code. For your solution, for different number of delimiters, I would like the last value to be repeated to the next row as well. Check the edit above.
